# How to Handle redirection in react-router-dom v6. Landing the user on desired page

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, react-router, react-router-dom, keycloak

I want to integrate the oauth2 keycloak for auth purpose in my react application. Below is my code

```
const RequireAuth = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  console.log(auth);
  return auth?.user ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    window.location = "https://localhost:8080/auth/realms/rocket/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=login-rocket&response_type=code"
  );
};
```

Redirect url is pointed to auth screen of the react app in keycloak which is `http://localhost:5173/auth`. when the redirection happens with `code` url param, I have to take the code, send it to backend and get the `access_token`.  Below is the code

```
const AuthDetails = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [params, setParams] = useSearchParams();
  console.log(params.get("code"));
  axios.post("/auth/login", qs.stringify({"grant_type": "authorization_code", "code": params.get("code")}))
  .then(response => {
    const token = response.data.body.response.access_token;
    console.log(token);
    auth.setToken(token);
    auth.setUser(jwtDecode(token).preferred_username);
    navigate("/", {replace: true})
  })
  .catch(ex => console.log(ex));
  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}
```

Now if the users types url `http://localhost:5173/{any}`, I want all the process happen and take the user to `/{any}` page. But due to page reloading, the `auth` data used is cleared and it is redirected to home page.

Main SPA Code.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
            <Route index element={<Joke />} />
            <Route path="chat" element={<ChatWindow />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="auth" element={<AuthDetails />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

How should I make the redirect store the auth data and land the user to `/{any}` screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried using `<Navigate to="" />` instead of `windows.location = ""`. But the problem with that approach is, the root domain is not changing.

Comment: It looks like `RequireAuth` should redirect to the authentication route `"/auth"`, e.g. `return <Navigate to"/auth" replace />;`, and `AuthDetails` needs to make the POST request as an ***intentional*** side-effect via the `useEffect` hook. Don't use `window.location` to mutate the URL as this reloads the page and the entire app.

Comment: @DrewReese Redirecting to `/auth` will bring the `AuthDetails` component to front but then I will not have `code` to make the post request. The `code` comes from the auth server redirection. So we need to redirect to the login screen of authorization server and come back to our app which erases the state. That is where I need the help.

Comment: Is there any reason your app can't redirect to your auth route to handle any authentication actions? It can then redirect out of the app to this external endpoint, get the token, get redirected back to the auth route, and then handled in-app from there.